# Why does java say a semicolon is expected when I already have one?

Tags: java

I tried compiling my code so I could then run it and test it, but it says that there is a semi-colon expected.

I tried deleting and re-inserting the semi-colon, but the error keeps appearing when I compile. The error is "GPACalculator.java:430: error: ';' expected"

```
if ((class71Honors.equals("Yes"))||(class71Honors.equals("Yes."))||(class71Honors.equals("yes"))||(class71Honors.equals("yes.")))
            {
               double class71GPA+=0.6;
            }
```

I don't expect a printed output, I just want the code to compile because it's the only error I have at the moment. Thanks! (this is all java by the way)

Comment: What is the use of declaring a variable as the *only* thing in its scope?

Answer (score 3):

This is invalid syntax.

```java
double class71GPA+=0.6;
```

First you need to define and initialize your variable:

```java
double class71GPA = 0;
```

And after that you can use it in statements. In your case:

```java
class71GPA += 0.6;
```

Comment: Thank you so much but I already had class71GPA instantiated in previous code. Is there something else that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @VivianaEsquivel so you no longer need to specify its type: just remove `double` from the expression.